# How to end Listen action

Tags: java, android, pepper

I'm struggling to understand how, and if it is possible, to end a listen action on Pepper after it is started. What i want to achieve in my application is the following:

- Pepper asks a question to the user, which in turn can answer either with voice or a touch input on the tablet.
- If the answer is negative, Pepper will have to execute an animation and at the same time reply with a phrase.

This is the part of the code to handle voice input, and it works as expected:

```
public void onRobotFocusGained(QiContext qiContext) {
         ...

        //Pepper greets the approached user
        animation_future = greeting_animation.async().run();
        //After the animation is finished, wait for human input
        animation_future.andThenConsume(chatting ->{
            listen = ListenBuilder.with(qiContext).withPhraseSet(response).buildAsync();
            listen.andThenConsume(heardPhrase->{
                //Pepper start listening
                result = heardPhrase.run();
                //If the response contains "yes"
                if( (result.getHeardPhrase().getText().toLowerCase()).equals("si")){
                    //User need helps, Pepper start discussing with it
                    helpNeeded_chat.async().run();
                    //Otherwise
                }else if( (result.getHeardPhrase().getText().toLowerCase()).equals("no")){
                    //No help is required, Pepper says goodbye
                    animation_future = goodbye_animation.async().run();
                    //A new user comes by - Restart scenario
                    animation_future.andThenConsume(restart->{
                        Log.i(TAG, "Interaction ended. Restarting.");
                        //Restart by starting this same activity
                        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

While this is the part that handles touch inputs (defined in its own method outside onRobotFocusGained):

```
final Button button_no = findViewById(R.id.button_no);
button_no.setOnClickListener(v->{
    ...
    listen.requestCancellation();
    //Help is refused - Restart scenario
    animation_future = goodbye_animation.async().run();
    animation_future.andThenConsume(restart->{
        Log.i(TAG, "Interaction ended. Restarting.");
        //Restart by starting this same activity
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    });
});
```

In this case since the Listen action keeps running then the warning ***Pepper can not speak while is listening*** is thrown thus preventing correct ending of the task.
What I have found is that the only method that might allow to terminate actions is **requestCancellation()** but it doesn't seems to work in my case, the boolean method **isCancelled()** to check whether the action is terminated keeps returning always *False*.

It is actually possible to stop the Listen action or do I have to entirely change the way in which my code is structured (i.e. use a chatbot from the very beginning)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are calling `listen.requestCancellation()`, you are in fact cancelling the *building* of the listen action.
You defined `listen` with:
`listen = ListenBuilder.with(qiContext).withPhraseSet(response).buildAsync();`.

Instead, you should cancel the future returned when you *run* the action: `result = heardPhrase.run();`.
Calling `result.requestCancellation()` should do the trick for you.

The thumb rule is that Qi SDK actions are first *built* then *run*.